# How to get values from array using index value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get values from a list using index value via for loop. but after getting and assigning them to another list it shows all values are undefined. How to solve this

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function Function() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [features, setFeatures] = useState({});
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const passingData = history.location.state; //array passed from prev page
    setData(passingData);
    console.log(data);//log=> {'id':01 ,'name':"name1"},{'id':02 ,'name':"name2"},{'id':03 ,'name':"name3"}

    const tFeatures = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      tFeatures.push(data[i]);
     }
    console.log(tFeatures);//output => [undefined, undefined, undefined]
  }, []);


  return <div></div>;
}

export default Function;
```

```js
console.log(data); // {'id':01 ,'name':"name1"},{'id':02 ,'name':"name2"},{'id':03 ,'name':"name3"}
```

```js
console.log(tFeatures) // [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Comment: Are the states in previous pages some kind of promise/async result? That may be it. Also, your useEffect is dependant on `history.location.state`

Comment: Why don't you set the `data` and  `tFeatures` in the same `useEffect`.

Comment: @Cunning yes it is, but if I assigned it to the new array without retrieving the index value it is assigning perfectly the whole list. but I want to get specific value using index

Comment: are you sure that the data state is an array?

Comment: Ok, based on the new edit, tFeatures is the problem. The effect for it runs first when component is mounting (`data = {} //initial state value`) and it's OK to be undefined. some how I think data is not changing beyond initial value, so the other effect is not getting called properly.

Comment: @ViniciusKatata yes I checked it from console.log()

Comment: A few things. First, add `history.location.state` in the useEffect dependencies, otherwise the effect gets triggered at every render cycle. Second, wrap the whole tFeatures array building logic within a condition checking if data is undefined.

Comment: @ViniciusKatata it shouldn't matter, object `{"0": "something"}` is equivalent to `["something"]` in JS

Comment: @UtkarshBhardwaj Actually, your first point is not valid. They defined the an empty dependency list, this means this effect is happening only one in the lifecycle and that's on mounting; no dependency list at all means at every point in render cycle. Your second point is super duper valid and regardless of debugging, it's good to check that.

Comment: @Medi. same result

Comment: Also if you're working with ES6 syntax and you're using all elements of data, you may want to use the spread (`[...]`) syntax. Like so: tFeatures = [...data]

Comment: Have you ever try to use higher oder array functions, like `forEach`

Comment: @Cunning I tried it in the same useEffect. but the result is the same

Comment: Thanks @Cunning. Seems like I can't edit that comment anymore. Reader beware.

Comment: @CrispenGari. i want to get some part from the list(like 3/10 values). that why I'm using for loop

Comment: If they are of promise nature, try using Promise.all(array_of_promises).then(resolve_callback).catch(reject_callbacl) and console.log to see if you have the correct data. look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: There are better tools for fetching part of an array as well @Nathindu. [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't undefined at the first render? Take a look at this
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-blackburn-1fvto?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Have you been able to sort it out. If so, how? What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `passingData` instead of `data`? By the time you call `console.log(data)`, it won't have been set yet (it's asynchronous). So either use `passingData` or extract the part that depends on `data` and put it in its own `useEffect()`.

```
function Function() {
    const history = useHistory();

    const [data, setData] = useState([]); // should be an array, not an object
    const [features, setFeatures] = useState([]); // should be an array, not an object

    useEffect(() => {
        const tFeatures = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            tFeatures.push(data[i]);
        }
    }, [data])

    useEffect(() => {
        const passingData = history.location.state;
        setData(passingData);
    }, [history.location.state]);


    return <div></div>;
}
```

or

```
function Function() {
    const history = useHistory();

    const [data, setData] = useState([]); // should be an array, not an object
    const [features, setFeatures] = useState([]); // should be an array, not an object

    useEffect(() => {
        const passingData = history.location.state;
        setData(passingData);
        const tFeatures = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            tFeatures.push(passingData[i]); // use passingData not data
        }
    }, [history.location.state]);


    return <div></div>;
}
```